# 415 Unsupported Media Type - Spring version

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc

I have this method on my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String test(@RequestBody Test test) {
    return test.getName();
}
```

My Test class:

```
public class Test implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1150931681075770764L;

    private String name;
    public String getName() {return name;}
    public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}
}
```

I post this json using:

```
{"name": "avocado"}
```

I also have this annotation:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

I'm using Advanced Rest Client to test it.
My request's Content-Type is set to "application/json".

If I set spring version to 4.0.9.RELEASE or earlier I get 200 OK code when post.

If I set spring version to 4.1.0.RELEASE or later I get 415 Unsupported Media Type.

What shoud I do in order to get code 200 setting spring version to 4.2.1.RELEASE?

Comment: post your `Test` object

Comment: Typically this is because you may not have specified the `Content-Type` or `Accept` headers, that should fix it across the board.

Comment: My request Content-Type is already set to "application/json" and Accept is `*/*`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to add

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test", method = RequestMethod.POST, 
    consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody String test(@RequestBody Test test) {
    return test.getName();
}
```

Also conversion works with the `HttpMessageConverter<?>` to be able to serialize/deserialize in JSON format you need to have Jackson libraries in your classpath then spring will be able to instantiate the `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`

Add this to your dependencies.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-json.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-json.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-json.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```